# JavaScript: Convert uploaded CSV file contents to Array

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

I need some help with converting uploaded csv file contents to an array using JavaScript code.

Following is what I have done so far:

I've a csv file, that contains list of all clientIDs e.g.

```
ClientIDs
1
2
3
```

Using following html code, I upload the file

```
<form id = "FileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div> <p><p>
       <b>Select file containing all clientIDs:</b>
       <input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="csv"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload"/>
       <input type="submit" name="FileUpload" value="Upload File"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

Now, the part I am stuck at. The JS that read and converts file contents

```
if(document.getElementById("FileUpload").value != "") {
   console.log("The file was uploaded");
   //Process the file and convert its contents to array
}
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to take a look at some of the code examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the id's are separated by new line, you can do something like this:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {
    var arr = e.target.result.split("\n");
    // Continue processing...
};

reader.readAsText(document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[0]);
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Thanks for the comment Andrei.. the only change I had to make was using readAsText instead of readAsDataURL. 
Other than that, its all working now.

Comment: You are correct, I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Hi Andrei, Another question, the answer works fine and displays correct value inside onload function, but when I try to print the value outside that function, the array still displays empty values. 
e.g.                 reader.onload = function (e) {
                    uploadedClientList = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    console.log("Take 1:" + uploadedClientList);
                };
            console.log("Take 2:" + uploadedClientList);

Take 1 works fine, but Take 2 is still empty

Comment: Ravi, this is the way JavaScript works. JavaScript is non-blocking: there is no guarantee that uploadedClientList will be set up before Take 2 executes. One way to enforce the order of execution is to use callback functions. I think this tutorial explains it pretty well: http://sebastianmetzger.com/handle-asynchronous-non-blocking-io-in-javascript/

Comment: Thanks Andrei.. That info was really helpful.. Task completed. :)